# Does someone has the cxLocalizer values for French and Spanish?

Tags: delphi, localization, devexpress

Dev.Express has changed quit some units in its last update (`DevExpressVCLProducts-11.1.3`).

So I decided to stop using my own translation components for on the fly translation of resource strings in the dev.express components (based on the [Free DevExpress Addons](http://www.freedevexpressaddons.com/) code and translations).

In stead I now will use there **cxLocalizer** component.

So at the moment I am looking for ini-files with their resource texts translated into Frech, Spanish and German.

- I already found the **Dutch** and **German** translations in the answer to one of [their knowledge base articles](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18138.aspx).

Can anyone help ? Maybe we can compile a list to translations in this question.

Comment: Always nice to receive a down vote without knowing why ?

Comment: +1 from me. I currently conside switching from cxIntl to cxLocalizer, too. But I guess the compilation of available files rather should go to the linked KB article.